# Manage ClickListener of button in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` to show items in a `ListView`. It has a `Button` and a `TextView`, I want that when the button gets pressed, change the text view's color to red, but if I click the button of another item of the list, besides of setting the textview of the item to red, it will set the textview's color of the rest of the items, to their original color.

It would be different if I were using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` as the layout of the `ListView`'s childs. I would only have to override the `setOnItemClickListener` of my list like this:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)view;
            if(tv1.getCurrentTextColor() != Color.RED){
                for(int i = 0; i < myList.getChildCount(); i++){
                  TextView tv2 = (TextView)myList.getChildAt(i);
                    tv2.setTextColor(tv1.getCurrentTextColor());
                }
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
```

But since I'm using a custom layout(also a custom adapter), I do not know how and where should I manage this, in the `OnItemClick()` method or in the `getView()` method of my custom adapter.

Comment: do you use a holder in your ListView adapter?

Comment: anyway to give you the answer, the simplest way is to set a tag for the button when you click to change the color for the button  eg (button.setTag(1);). Then in your adapter you need to get the tag and say if (button.getTag() == 1) {Change the color) else (change to original color))

Comment: @Tasos, no, should I?